# Isotope with dynamic hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following problem:

I want to make a page where the images are dynamically fixed as in this web: http://www.fosterandpartners.com/projects/ and, at the same time, each of these images should have a hover containing certain information to the image.

After googling a bit I found a Js called Isotope allows me to do the arrangement of the pictures, even though I do not have a way to make the hover without being so problematic.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Are you talking about the background image or another part of the page?

Comment: Make the image the `background-image` and show the text when you hover over the div

Comment: The Masonry worded just fine to fix my problem. THX u guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't often recommend jQuery, but since you tagged it I'll assume you're already using it, so for a quick and simple solution checkout [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) by David DeSandro.